# as_ldt_init failed to initialize -- C++ client

Tags: c++, aerospike

just day before i started to work with aerospike. I have some problem while writing one sample using LDT (Large data types -- Large List). I want to create a key with currdate with appended as key (20160419_2000_List) and later i will add raw data (byte array) as list values.
For that i am able to connect the database correctly, but i am not able to create key for list. Can you please guide me on this.
You can refer the following code to get idea of what i am doing exactly.

```
 m_sTFPKeyStr.assign(datevalue);  //datavalue consists datatime string
        m_sTFPListStr.assign("List_");
        m_sTFPListStr.append(datevalue);
        as_key_init_str(&m_sTFPKey, m_sInputNameSpace.c_str(), m_sInputSetName.c_str(), m_sTFPKeyStr.c_str());

        if (!as_ldt_init(m_sTFPListKey, m_sTFPListStr.c_str(), AS_LDT_LLIST, NULL))
        {
            memset(logmessage, 0x0, sizeof(logmessage));
            sprintf(logmessage, "CDataBaseManager::SaveTFP Fails to initialize tfplist key %s", m_sTFPListStr.c_str());
            m_pCaptureManager->m_pLogMgr->LogMsg(logmessage);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a regular list, and atomic list operations to do this? What functionality of LList do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the length of  `m_sTFPListStr`  in your code.

The codes of function `as_ldt_init` which will check the parameters :

```
as_ldt * as_ldt_init(as_ldt * ldt, const as_bin_name name, const as_ldt_type type, const as_udf_module_name module)
{
  if (!name || name[0] == '\0' || strlen(name) > AS_BIN_NAME_MAX_LEN
     || (module && strlen(module) > AS_UDF_MODULE_MAX_LEN) )
  {
    return NULL;
  }
  ...
}
```

As the value of AS_BIN_NAME_MAX_LEN:

```
#define AS_BIN_NAME_MAX_LEN (AS_BIN_NAME_MAX_SIZE - 1)
#define AS_BIN_NAME_MAX_SIZE 15
```